# I can't figure out how to make the year not negative in my leap year calculator

Tags: c++

Write a program that prints the day number of the year, given the date in the form month-day-year. For example, if the input is 1-1-2006, the day number is 1; if the input is 12-25-2006, the day number is 359. The program should check for a leap year. A year is a leap year if it is divisible by 4, but not divisible by 100. For example, 1992 and 2008 are divisible by 4, but not by 100. A year that is divisible by 100 is a leap year if it is also divisible by 400. For example, 1600 and 2000 are divisible by 400. However, 1800 is not a leap year because 1800 is not divisible by 400.

I can't figure out how to make it so my program doesn't account for the dash when entering the date. Whenever I type in 01-24-2008, It keeps trying to figure out if the year -2008 is a leap year, not 2008.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int month, day, year, day_num = 0;
  cout << "Enter date in format (MM-DD-YYYY): ";
  cin >> month >> day >> year;

  // Array of days in each month
  int days_in_month[12] = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

  // Check for leap year
  if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
    days_in_month[1] = 29;
  }

  // Calculate day number of year
  for (int i = 0; i < month - 1; i++) {
    day_num += days_in_month[i];
  }
  day_num += day;

  cout << "Day number of year: " << day_num << endl;

  if (days_in_month[1] == 29) {
    cout << year << " is a leap year." << endl;
  } else {
    cout << year << " is not a leap year." << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that your question would be of higher quality if you posted a [mre] of the problem, instead of your entire code. According to your question, your immediate problem has nothing to do with the leap-year calculations, but only with how to convert a string representing a date into integers representing month, day and year. Therefore, most of of your posted code is redundant.

Comment: An easy workaround would to to write the date in format MM DD YYYY (with spaces as separator). Or you can use [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) instead.